# Check whether the given matrix is diagonalizable or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am stuck on the following question:

> [image]

This question carries only $1$ mark. So,without going into details how can I check whether the given matrix $M$ and $M^2=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &15  &45 \\ 
 0&16  &45 \\ 
 0&0  &81 
\end{pmatrix}$ are diagonalizable  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If eigenvalues are all distinct, then the matrix is diagonalizable. Since the matrix is upper diagonal, the diagonal entries are precisely the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

A real matrix with distinct *real* eigenvalues are diagonalisable over $\mathbb{R}$. More generally, if the characteristic polynomial of a matrix can be split into distinct linear factors over a field $\mathbb{F}$, the matrix is diagonalisable over $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So,both $M,M^2$ are diagonalisable. Am I right?

Comment: @learner Yes, they are.